ATen parallel_for grain_size 0
I want to use the at::parallel_for to do my for loop in parallel, and reading other code, I noticed that the grain_size is frequently set to 0.
I've read the description at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/Parallel.h, and I'm not still sure what the grain_size 0 means.
The description says:

grain_size: number of elements per chunk. impacts the degree of parallelization

